# composer autoload namespaces missing?

Tags: composer-php

I'm developing on a project which uses Monolog, which requires Psr/log.
When I use Monolog by autoload, it then complains about missing Psr\Log\LoggerInterface.
So I look through the composer generated autoload_namespaces.php, and I couldn't find Psr being registered.

Here's the contents of my vendor/autoload_namespaces.php

```
return array(
'Symfony\\Component\\Process' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/process/',
'Monolog' => $vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/',
'Imagine' => $vendorDir . '/imagine/Imagine/lib/',
'Gedmo' => $vendorDir . '/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/',
'Gaufrette' => $vendorDir . '/knplabs/gaufrette/src/',
'Evenement' => $vendorDir . '/evenement/evenement/src',
'Doctrine\\ORM' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib/',
'Doctrine\\DBAL' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib/',
'Doctrine\\Common' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib/',
'Assetic' => $vendorDir . '/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/',
'Analog' => $vendorDir . '/analog/analog/lib/',
);
```

Is composer supposed to register namespaces for all projects which has {autoload} defined in their composer.json files? (I checked both Monolog and Psr/Log, they both have {autoload} defined.)

Or am I getting the wrong idea about composer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add

```
"psr/log": "1.0.0"
```

in your composer.json require block. The project `monolog/monolog` doesn't require `psr/log` [you can verify that in monolog's composer.json file].

Then run `composer update` to update your autoloader file.

[**UPDATE**] Made a mistake.

I am using monolog 1.2.* and it doesn't require `psr/log`. After monolog 1.3.*, it does requires `psr/log`.  In that case, composer should load `psr/log` namespace in vendor/autoload_namespaces.php.

For example, I just updated my composer.json to have

```
"monolog/monolog": "1.3.*",
```

in the require block. Then run `composer update monolog/monolog` [you can run this command again to see if it fixes your problem]

> ```
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
>     Loading from cache
>
>   - Removing monolog/monolog (1.2.1)
>   - Installing monolog/monolog (1.3.1)
>     Downloading: connection...
>     Downloading: 100%
> ```

Then in my vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php, I found this proper entry:

```
    'Psr\\Log\\' => $vendorDir . '/psr/log',
```

This should work. Sometimes I also just run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to re-generate vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php file again.

Comment: I see the following in monolog's composer.json file. Or am I interpreting it wrong?

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "psr/log": "~1.0"
    },

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: Haven't tracked monolog/monolog for a while. You are right. It should setup the autoload_namespaces.php automatically. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually confused by the number of autoload_namespaces.php there are.
The one I posted in my question was in `vendor/`, then I found another one in `vendor/.composer/`, and finally found the CORRECT one in **`vendor/composer/`**.

Sorry for the answering my own (stupid) question but it's worth mentioning in case some other developers have the same trouble.

And thanks to @Chuan Ma for the answer.

Comment: Having so many files is probably related to legacy from usage of very old versions of Composer (first alpha releases of composer were using different locations than today)

Answer (score 0):

Composer registers classes based on the `autoload`in the project's `composer.json` file, e.g.

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "path/to/FirstClass.php",
      "path/to/SecondClass.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

Normally `composer update` will automatically regenerate `autoload_namespaces.php` lists all namespaces which your application can use (unless you're using multiple autoloaders).

If the namespaces are missing, here is the command to update the composer autoloader directly:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Then you need to make sure you include the autoloader at the top of our scripts:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

See: [How to directly autoload classes with Composer?](http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer)

If it's still failing, double check the syntax in the failing project's `composer.json` file (especially `autoload` section). To debug, try running composer with `-vvv` or under [XDebug](https://xdebug.org).